# is the operator overloading slow down performance?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

im trying to make memory pool class and have to overload operator[], but theres a huge(2x) slow down:

- T(overloaded) = 76.4043 ns
- T(not-ovld) = 28.6016 ns

is it normal or im doing something wrong? thanks for help :)

compiler vc++2013
optimization disabled/full - same thing

class(main.cpp):

```
template<class T>
class pool{
public:
    T *cell;
    size_t size = 0;
public:
    pool(const size_t n ){
        size = n;
        cell = new T[size];
    }
    T& operator [](const size_t i) { return cell[i]; }
    T operator [](const size_t i)const { return cell[i]; }
};
```

main(main.cpp):

```
template<class T>
T F( T x){
    return x/2 % 100;
}

#define test_count 10000000

int main()
{
    pool<unsigned int> P(test_count);
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    resettimer();

    // test 1
    for (int i = 0; i < test_count; i++)
        P[i] = F(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < test_count; i++)
        sum = sum + P[i];

    cout << sum << endl;
    //
    printtimer();
    sum = 0;
    resettimer();

    // test2
    for (int i = 0; i < test_count; i++)
        P.cell[i] = F(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < test_count; i++)
        sum = sum + P.cell[i];

    cout << sum << endl;
    //
    printtimer();

    int q;
    cin >> q;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And now switch tests... first test2 and then test1. Might surprise you.

Comment: Did you turn optimizations on?

Comment: What compiler and optimization level are you using?

Comment: switched. same thing 2.8 vs 7.6. compiler vc++2013 optimization disabled , (trying optimization like for spoj)

Comment: I did some experiments. I don't use vc++2013, but clang. But I see exactly, what I expected: The first test takes much longer than the second one. Both tests are roughly the same when I comment one out at a time. Curently too tired to pinpoint the exact problem, but benchmarks like yours are always problematic, since one can never be sure, what exactly one measures.

Comment: hm i tried one at time, still the same. It measures that memory time access though overloaded operator or function( .get(i) and set(i) ) is much slower than direct/manually. And that is my question am i wrong? what i have to do to achieve the same performance?

Comment: No idea. Do something wrong? I doubt it. I copy pasted your code. I just had to replace  resettimer() and printtimer(). And my results are totally different. There might be a speed difference, but hard to see with a few tests. The values fluctuate. I would have to do some graphical evaluation, but I am not that interested. Or I could look at the generated assembly code... the would probably be the most precise method.

Comment: ill try it with diffrent compiler etc. btw i use chrono nanosec. Thanks for your replay :) how to check/find that assambly code?

Comment: I only know how to do it with the gcc. The gcc has an option, to stop processing after assembler code generation. No idea if something like this is possible with vc++2013.

Comment: checked on code-blocks gcc, times: notovrl 7.7004 ns, ovrl 12.3007 ns. notovrl 1.6 times faster. Its kind wierd for me that the gcc much faster than vc++(compering execute times).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Debug build, in Release build (optimization n stuff) all works like it should. Hehe stupid mistake but taught me something :)
Conclusion - dont measure performence in debug mode ;)